# Lodash find array in array

Tags: lodash

I have an array that looks like this:

```
   var roles = [ 
           { "label": "Super Auditor", "value": 4 }, 
           { "label": "Super Finance Officer", "value": 3 }, 
           { "label": "Super Manager", "value": 2 }, 
           { "label": "Super Admin", "value": 1 } 
   ]
```

I need to find if it is in array and get that object.

```
var needToFind = [4, 1]
```

Expected Results:

```
var results =[
              { "label": "Super Auditor", "value": 4 }, 
              { "label": "Super Admin", "value": 1 } 
            ]
```

I just don't know how to do it. TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`_.intersectionWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#intersectionWith):

```js
var roles = [ 
  { "label": "Super Auditor", "value": 4 }, 
  { "label": "Super Finance Officer", "value": 3 }, 
  { "label": "Super Manager", "value": 2 }, 
  { "label": "Super Admin", "value": 1 }
]

var needToFind = [4, 1]

var result = _.intersectionWith(roles, needToFind, (a, b) => a.value === b)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer using VanillaJS

```js
const roles = [ 
           { "label": "Super Auditor", "value": 4 }, 
           { "label": "Super Finance Officer", "value": 3 }, 
           { "label": "Super Manager", "value": 2 }, 
           { "label": "Super Admin", "value": 1 } 
];


const needToFind = [4, 1];

const results = roles.filter(obj => needToFind.includes(obj.value))

console.log(results)
```

Basically you apply `filter` on `roles` and using `includes` to see if value exist in `needtoFind`